# How to allow esc secuence charater in existing alphanumeric validation expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am using following validation expression for validating string for accepting alphanumeric characters only

```
(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,50})$
```

But it does not accept characters like `~, !, (, ), [, ], {, }` etc, how do I add expression in above to accept all these characters?

Thanks,

Comment: You have to escape them like `\!`. You should probably have a look at a basic regex tutorial.

Comment: but how? Can you please give me the example for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) for each of those characters.

Example (needs repeating for all character types):

```
string pattern = "(?" 
    + Regex.Escape("!")
    + "^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,50})$";
```

Comment: Are you sure this precise `!` needs escaping ?

Comment: @dystroy Nah, I'm merely illustrating how to escape :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    string _strTemp = "USer ,()TeXt~!";
    if (Regex.IsMatch(_strTemp, @"^[a-zA-Z 0-9.!~(){},]+$"))
    {
        //Valid Input
    }
    else
    {
        //Invalid Input
    }
```